Why cannot we adapt Barvinok type counting techniques to general convex integer programs?
Decision problems in Integer Linear Programming have Lenstra type algorithms (https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~lenstrahw/PUBLICATIONS/1983i/art.pdf) have been generalized to convex integer program techniques (See Complexity of integer quasiconvex polynomial
optimization by Sebastian Heinz).
What is the difficulty in generalizing Barvinok type counting integer points in Linear Integer Programming techniques (https://barvinok.sourceforge.io/) to counting integer points in convex integer programming?

Not sure exactly what you're asking. Higher-degree polynomials are a lot harder to handle than linear polynomials. Even in two dimensions, we have Pick's formula for a polygon, but even counting the exact number of integer points inside a circle is not a trivial problem.
